# RPC ACK in distributed systems (VIew service mit 6.824 lab2)

Tags: networking, rpc, distributed

As shown in the picture:[View service](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/labs/lab-2a-vs.png)

Server 1 Ping(2), so View 2 in the Viewservice should be ACKed, and it will jump into View3, why does the Viewservice return View2 to server 1 two times?

Answer (score 0):

It's course Homework. You should do it on your own.